# Button with Number and Text

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML button, I have to display it just like smart phone dialpad. like number and ABC etc.

```
<a href="" class="button">
    1
    <span>ABC</span>
</a>
```

everything is fine except the text is not visible in the button. How can I solve that ?

Comment: What do you want it to do? Clearly the text is not visible due to styling - what style do you want?

Comment: I want to display it like a smart phone dial key. But there was some design problem with my css.

Comment: play with few CSS and you will get flexible button - http://jsfiddle.net/2nv7A/19/ check dial

Comment: If someone answered your question, you should upvote and check as accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the style of the span to wrap correctly.

add `display: inline-block;` to your `a span` selector so that it looks like this:

`a span {font-size:8px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0em;
    margin-top:-5px;
    font-style:italic;
    display: inline-block;
}`

The best solution is usually the simplest. In this case, just a one line addition.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a `height` to your button element. Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nv7A/8/

```
.button {
    ...
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to increase the height, I just want to make the number and text visible in the center of the button

Comment: @user3470629 You might want to specify that in your post then

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a span {
    font-size:8px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0em;
    margin-top:-15px; // pulled up the text a little more
    margin-bottom:10px; // pushed down the margin at the bottom
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Fiddle around with these and you'll find the best one for you

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2nv7A/17/)**

Answer (score 0):

U can use overflow property to show the text cutting off and then can manage height of your element.

```
 .button {
        position: relative;
        width: 62px;
```

> overflow: visible;

```
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    /*border-radius: 7px;*/
    Outline: none;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    border-color:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your positioning, decrease your line-height and then remove your span height (which was set to 0 preventing it from appearing) then it seems to work fine. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2nv7A/18/)

```
.button {
    width: 62px;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    /*border-radius: 7px;*/
    Outline: none;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    border-color:#ccc;
}

a{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:25px;
overflow:hidden;
    font-size:12px;
}


a span {font-size:8px;
text-transform:uppercase;
display:block;
text-align:center;
font-style:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decresea the `line-height` property of .a AND increase the `line-height` of a. span.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the margins on your span. Use this CSS:

```
a span {font-size:8px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0em;
    margin-top:-10px;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the `display:block` for the `span` tag, which should be `display:inline-block;`:

```
a span {
  font-size:8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  display:inline-block; /* <---- here */
  text-align:center;
  line-height:0em;
  margin-top:-5px;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nv7A/20/)